# loop to return all matches

Tags: php, loops, foreach

With the following code I am matching a 9 digit string. I am successful at returning the first instance without using a loop, but I would like to have this look through an entire page and return each 9 digit string and so far its not doing that. It only returns `NULL`.

```
$source = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/cd=([0-9]{9})/', $source, $match);

foreach ($match[1] as $output)
{
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `\d` shortcut :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`preg_match_all`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

From the [`preg_match` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> **preg_match()** returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because **preg_match()** will stop searching after the first match. [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject. **preg_match()** returns **FALSE** if an error occurred.

The `$match` array might look different, so you have to adjust your loop.